# Not able to position the html tag with bs4 and re

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-re

I am trying to use BS4 to scrap public filing of earning release, there is a keyword named "reconciliation(s)", so I tried to search with Regex. I found all of the reconciliation keyword should be in some div tag, so I set my search function to be: `for text_tag in soup.find_all('div', text=re.compile('(reconciliation)|(reconciliations)', re.IGNORECASE), recursive=True):`, but somehow I found cases where the result returned is empty, here is one of them:

```
         <div style="clear:both;max-width:100%;position:relative;">
          <p style="font-family:'Times New Roman','Times','serif';font-size:10pt;line-height:1.19;text-align:center;margin:0pt;">
           <font style="font-size:11pt;">
            PENSKE AUTOMOTIVE GROUP, INC.
           </font>
          </p>
          <p style="font-family:'Times New Roman','Times','serif';font-size:10pt;line-height:1.19;text-align:center;margin:0pt;">
           <font style="font-size:11pt;">
            Consolidated Non-GAAP Reconciliations
           </font>
          </p>
```

It is under the div tag with word reconciliation

I tried nothing, since I don't know where to start to fix it.....

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lambda:`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
         <div style="clear:both;max-width:100%;position:relative;">
          <p style="font-family:'Times New Roman','Times','serif';font-size:10pt;line-height:1.19;text-align:center;margin:0pt;">
           <font style="font-size:11pt;">
            PENSKE AUTOMOTIVE GROUP, INC.
           </font>
          </p>
          <p style="font-family:'Times New Roman','Times','serif';font-size:10pt;line-height:1.19;text-align:center;margin:0pt;">
           <font style="font-size:11pt;">
            Consolidated Non-GAAP Reconciliations
           </font>
          </p>
         </div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")


for text_tag in soup.find_all(
    lambda tag: tag.name == "div" and "reconciliation" in tag.get_text().lower()
):
    print(text_tag)
```

Prints:

```html
<div style="clear:both;max-width:100%;position:relative;">
<p style="font-family:'Times New Roman','Times','serif';font-size:10pt;line-height:1.19;text-align:center;margin:0pt;">
<font style="font-size:11pt;">
            PENSKE AUTOMOTIVE GROUP, INC.
           </font>
</p>
<p style="font-family:'Times New Roman','Times','serif';font-size:10pt;line-height:1.19;text-align:center;margin:0pt;">
<font style="font-size:11pt;">
            Consolidated Non-GAAP Reconciliations
           </font>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, would you also mind to tell me why wasn't my orginal code won't work? I am trying to learn the library.

Answer (score 1):

simply do this, provide a custom function which will filter the divs and return only the divs which have this value as text (lower cased)

```py
# imports
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# function to search in the divs
def contains_reconciliation(tag):
    return 'reconciliation' in tag.text.lower()

# Search results
result_divs = soup.find_all(contains_reconciliation, 'div')

# do something with the results
for div in result_divs:
    print(div)
```

## According to your html code you posted, you want to search for the `font` element and not a `div`

```py
# imports
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# function to search in the divs
def contains_reconciliation(tag):
    return 'reconciliation' in tag.text.lower()

# Search results
result_fonts = soup.find_all(contains_reconciliation, 'font ')

# do something with the results
for font in result_fonts:
    # you can get the parent div if thats what you are looking for
    div = font.parent().parent()
    print(div)
    print(font)
```

Comment: yes, but sadly the data is very inconsistent, some of them are in p , or b or other tags, but I found they all underdiv tag